# C++ Struct Bubble Sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, iostream, bubble-sort

I have to bubble sort a C++ struct only with iostream and fstream, something just seems to be going wrong though (see input and output below).

```
void sortCarsByPrice(Cars carsArray[])
{
    int index1;
    int index2;
    int index3;
    int swap;
    int yearTemp;
    char makeTemp;
    char modelTemp;
    float priceTemp;
    int availTemp;
    do
    {
        swap = 0;
        for (index1 = 0; index1 < 5; index1++)
        {
            if (carsArray[index1].price > carsArray[index1 + 1].price)
            {
                yearTemp = carsArray[index1].year;
                carsArray[index1].year = carsArray[index1 + 1].year;
                carsArray[index1 + 1].year = yearTemp;

                for (index2 = 0; carsArray[index1].make[index2] != '\0' && carsArray[index1 + 1].make[index2] != '\0'; index2++)
                {
                    makeTemp = carsArray[index1].make[index2];
                    carsArray[index1].make[index2] = carsArray[index1 + 1].make[index2];
                    carsArray[index1 + 1].make[index2] = makeTemp;
                }

                for (index3 = 0; carsArray[index1].model[index3] != '\0' && carsArray[index1 + 1].model[index3] != '\0'; index3++)
                {
                    modelTemp = carsArray[index1].model[index3];
                    carsArray[index1].model[index3] = carsArray[index1 + 1].model[index3];
                    carsArray[index1 + 1].model[index3] = modelTemp;
                }

                priceTemp = carsArray[index1].price;
                carsArray[index1].price = carsArray[index1 + 1].price;
                carsArray[index1 + 1].price = priceTemp;

                availTemp = carsArray[index1].available;
                carsArray[index1].available = carsArray[index1 + 1].available;
                carsArray[index1 + 1].available = availTemp;

                swap += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (swap != 0);
    cout << "SORTED!" << endl;
    return; 

}
```

input:

```
    0 2014 Toyota Tacoma $115.12 0
    1 2015 Ford Fusion $90.89 1
    2 2009 Dodge Neon $45.25 0
    3 2015 Ford F150 $112.83 1
    4 2016 Subaru Outback $71.27 1
```

output:(after sorting)

```
0 999984304 �yota Ծ0#on $-1.84172e+33 32566
1 2009 Dodg Neonma $45.25 0
2 2016 Subae Outb $71.27 1
3 2015 Ford Fusi $90.89 1
4 2015 Fordru F150U�� $112.83 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are 5 elements in your array, and you use `index1 + 1` as an index inside your loop, then you only want `index1` to go up to 4.  As written, you are allowing `index1` to go up to 5, which means `index1 + 1` is 6, which is presumably off the end of the array.

Better yet, you might want to add an additional argument to your function that is the number of elements in the array, rather than having a mysterious (and incorrect) 5 in the middle of your sorting function.